# Microsoft Visual C++ Crash when building qgis 1.8.0 Windows 7 64bit

Tags: qgis, windows-7, visual-c++

I have a problem building the source of qgis1.8.0 in Windows 7 64bit.
i am trying to follow this instructions in this page:
http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/17/Building_QGIS_from_Source?version=2#Building-on-Windows
the dependencys are all installed succesfully and the generation of qgis1.8.0.sln is succesful too.
but in the release solution configuration build,  always Microsoft Visual C++ crash without problem report.

Anybody know how to fix the problem with  Microsoft Visual C++?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug with the MS C++ linker.  Do a search for the error number and there is a hotfix for it.

Comment: Do you know how to find error number outside MS C++?

Comment: There should be a error code in the console when it crashed, just google for that.

Comment: I dont have an error code in the console, I have only a Dialog appear with message : Microsoft VC Express has encountred a problem and needs to close.

Comment: i have this error when i try to use msbuild command :error MSB6006: "VCBuild.exe" exited with code -1073741819